# SQL Query insert error

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

So I'm currently trying to establish a database connection to my server and my insertion is having some problems. My query works when I manually try to plug it into phpmyadmin and a single row gets inserted.

However, when I try to load a page with the below code, it seems to hit the database 3 times. I tried using exit() right after my query to see if there was any weird loops, but it still got entered 3 times into the database. Is there anything that seems weird here?

```
//timestamp
$t = time();
$stamp = date("Y-m-d", $t);


//create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

//check connection
if($conn->connect_error){
  die("connection failed: ".$conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connection Successful"."<br>";

$name = "hi";
$affiliation = "yo";
$note = "wat";

$sql = "INSERT INTO `$table` (`name`, `affiliation`, `notes`, `timestamp`) VALUES ('$name', '$affiliation', '$note', '$stamp')";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if($result){
  echo "Data entered successfully";
  echo "<br>".$sql;
} else{
  echo "Error: " .$sql."<br>".$conn->error;
}


$conn->close();
```

MORE INFO*****

So here is a sample output for the whole table during one session

id: 281 - Name: yo wat 2016-09-03 19:18:09

id: 282 - Name: yo wat 2016-09-03 19:18:11

id: 283 - Name: yo wat 2016-09-03 19:18:11

id: 284 - Name: yo wat 2016-09-03 19:20:55

As you can tell by the timestamp, one gets added in one session and it is correct. However, shortly after that one is added 2 more instances of the query are run and put in. So the reason I was seeing 3 outputs per refresh is because of the 2 extra inserts that get through. (The 2 extra + the 1 correct insert)

I'm mystified as to why it does this, because it seems to be a server-related issue. I'm running mariadb and things look correct, but maybe something isn't closing correctly?

Comment: Do you see three new rows after every refresh?

Comment: Yes - I refresh the page and then refresh my database, 3 rows keep getting added

Comment: have u passed $table as table name

Comment: i tried yr code with passing $table = 'demo'; and it working fine

Comment: yea I added my table name and it does go into the correct table. It goes in 3 times though, not sure why... My fields are all indexes except the id, would that make a difference?

Comment: i don't think it matter

Comment: Not sure why it's happening for me then... any clue?

Comment: Show the full code.

Comment: can you please echo the query and run in phpmyadmin..see

Comment: I echoed the query and ran it in phpmyadmin, that worked fine - just 1 inserted. But right after $result = $conn->query($sql) 3 rows get inserted

Comment: @AndrejLudinovskov That is actually my full code. The only part I didn't add is my server info* like user pass and servername, and <?php?>

Comment: I do not think that the code in the question has any issues. However, your application may invoke the above code multiple times.

Comment: @Shadow Yea that's what I've been thinking, but I'm not sure how. I'm running the code as a pure page, just by itself. I've been trying to figure out why it might go a few times, but I don't think it's loading multiple times. So when I tried printing out the db in the same instance, only one is added, but it seems like it continues to add after the code ends or something in that ballpark.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Just increment arbitrary session variable and check its value after the run

Comment: @tadman I was planning to escape my strings (should take care of injection attempts?), all my input/output here were just examples. Thanks for the heads up though.

Comment: @Shadow Wouldn't session variables reset when page reloads? If you mean the end of the file, I tried printing the num rows for a select statement at the end, and it just shows *that 1 was added*. It is running the extra statements after the file ends or something (which is confusing me)

Comment: Session variables are not reset whent the page is reloaded, unless you instruct php to reset them.

Comment: @Shadow could you explain how to do this? I was just trying  $_SESSION['value']++;
from seeing something online, and it's not really changing. I know I can't set a value since it'll reset(?)

Comment: There are hundreds of tutorials out there that describe how to use php session, including php's own official website.

Comment: @Tyler Manual escaping is more work and also means a simple mistake can open a giant hole. Use placeholder values whenever possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I don't think this is a fix to the problem since I wasn't able to directly get it working, but using a separate html file to submit a form with post.php I was able to get correct results (1 entry). The reason why the page itself adds 3 entries per refresh is still unknown, but what I am doing now is something satisfactory.

I would like to know if someone knows a reason to why this happens, but for now, the immediate problem is solved.